# Structuring Cucumber JVM step definitions in different java files

Tags: cucumber, appium, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit, cucumber-java

I am working on an automation project based on Appium-cucumber-Java, which will be growing over time.

Currently, I have Step definitions Given,When, Then in one file for iOS & another file for Android.
Both of these, files extend from a common basetest class.
I initialize required Page Objects using new keyword in both of these files.

Now, I would like to modularise it little bit & create a CommonStepDefs file. But I am starting to get nullpointer exception.

Can you please suggest with any method similar to this or sample example to build this

Thanks in advance.

```
public class AndroidTestsStepDefs_usingFactory extends BaseTestClass {

AndroidChooseCountryPage androidChooseCountryPage;
AndroidCountrySelectionPage androidCountrySelectionPage;
OrderPrints orderPrints;
AndroidHomePage androidHomePage;
TourPage tourPage;

public AndroidTestsStepDefs_usingFactory() throws IOException, AWTException {
}


@Given("^the app has been installed$")
public void the_app_has_been_installed() throws Throwable {
    initializeDriver("android");
    super.setCoreAppType("Android");
}
```

Comment: Please provide more details, which line exactly throws exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are interested in sharing state between your step definitions files.

The idiomatic to share state in Java is to create a common object that is shared between all steps using dependency injection.

If your project uses a dependency injection framework, use the same for sharing state between the step definition classes. Cucumber-JVM supports many different dependency injection frameworks. Yours is probably supported.

If you don't use a dependency injection, I suggest using PicoContainer.

I have written two blog post on the topic. Sharing state using

- PicoContainer:
  http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2017/04/01/sharing-state-between-steps-in-cucumberjvm-using-picocontainer
- Spring:
  http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2017/06/24/sharing-state-between-steps-in-cucumberjvm-using-spring

Comment: Thanks a lot really appriciated.

Comment: Thanks a lot really appreciated. Two more queries - 1) Could Spring ApplicationContext be used to temporarily stored handy stuff or do we need to create some sort of data model. 2) I am using Cucumber+Appium+Java and on this background, bit confused on whether to go for TestNG ITestContext or Spring's ApplicationContext to store above referred states. Kindly provide some thought on this. Thanks

Comment: I would probably store whatever I need in my own World-object. A World-object is a rather uncomplicated structure that will give a lot of freedom and I don't need to learn yet another framework.

Comment: One more query- I have just started to use TestNG (cucumber class extending AbstractTestNGCucumberTests class). A) So basically, how could we achieve parallel run using Maven+PicoContainer+Cucumber . Since as per my understanding its not easy to have parallel runs using Maven surefire & that's why people use TestNG.  B) Or is it possible to achieve parallel run without using TestNG i.e. somehow using PicoContainer, Maven & Cucumber-JVM. Kindly advise. Thanks

Comment: I don't know. I haven explored running Cucumber in parallel.

Comment: Pico container works nicely. Kindly advise how to arrange cucumber After and Before hooks.Reson for asking - Its not permitted to have cucumber After hook in BaseClass. Do they need to be present in all StepDefs classes ? Exception in thread "main" cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: You're not allowed to extend classes that define Step Definitions or hooks. class stepDefs.PrintTestsStepDefs extends class core.BaseTestClass

Comment: Ask a new question. Adding questions in a comment will make it hard for others to find.